# Crash when append item to array

Tags: arrays, swift

I working on a feature where I have to stack some WS calls when I am waiting to get some results. But sometimes I got a crash. I am so curious because is a KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE.

this is the code where got the crash

```swift
    protocol ObservableProtocol: class {
    var observers: [DispatchWorkItem] { get set }
    func addObserver(_ block: @escaping () -> Void)
    func notifyObservers()
    func removeAllObservers()
}

class Observable: ObservableProtocol {
    internal var observers: [DispatchWorkItem] = []

//  In this function is where got the crash, on the append
    func addObserver(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.observers.append( DispatchWorkItem {
           block()
        })
    }
    
    func notifyObservers() {
        observers.forEach({
            DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: $0)
        })
        removeAllObservers()
    }
    
    func removeAllObservers() {
        observers.removeAll()
    }
    
    deinit {
        observers.removeAll()
    }
}
```

also, I tried this one in case got entries from multiple sites

```swift
    func addObserver(_ block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.observers.append( DispatchWorkItem {
                block()
            })
        }
    }
```

But I always got the same stack trace when crash:

```txt
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE 0x0000005886849d90

Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x194cadc88 _swift_release_dealloc + 24
1  MyProject                      0x1030ff004 specialized Array._createNewBuffer(bufferIsUnique:minimumCapacity:growForAppend:) + 4351750148
2  MyProject                      0x102f81e80 closure #1 in Observable.addObserver(_:) + 4350189184 (<compiler-generated>:4350189184)
3  MyProject                      0x102140300 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4335239936 (<compiler-generated>:4335239936)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1909ada84 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1909af81c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1909c110c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 688
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1909c17d8 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 112
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1dca32768 _pthread_wqthread + 216
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1dca3974c start_wqthread + 8
```

Does somebody know what I'm doing wrong or the reason for this crash?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: DispatchWorkItems execute a function an undefined function but does work well. the problem is when sometimes I append more items to the array

Comment: @PhilipDukhov what do mean abut define? do mean di this? : 
let item = DispatchWorkItem { block() }
self.observers.append(item)

Comment: @gvizeu my bad, haven't worked with them, thought it's some your class, but it's a system one=)

Comment: Are you calling the `addObserver` function from multiple threads/queues? In this case you need some kind of synchronization, because `Array` is not thread-safe.
Also, `DispatchQueue.global()` is a concurrent queue - so not suitable for synchronization in this case.

Comment: @FlorianFriedrich is called only from a singleton on de Base NetworkManager so I assume that is from the same queue. but anyways in order to try, Could you send me your proposal of synchronization to make this array safe? Also, I was thinking about use de Set or NSOrderedSet because I have read that we can manage multiple entries at the same time

Comment: A singleton doesn't mean it's not accessed from multiple threads/queues... :)

I'd use a private serial DispatchQueue and synchronize your access to the array by wrapping it in `queue.sync`. Newly created DispatchQueues are serial by default when using the initializer like `DispatchQueue(label: "your-label")`. Just don't pass the `.concurrent` flag to its attributes.

Comment: So just to confirm do you mean to do that? 
`        
DispatchQueue(label: "any_label").sync {
            self.observers.append( DispatchWorkItem {
                block()
            })
        }
`
@FlorianFriedrich

Comment: You need to store the serial queue. So in your `Observable` class you'd have a `private let observersLock = DispatchQueue(label: "observers-lock")`. And then in every place you access `observers`, you'd do a `observersLock.sync { /* do something with observers */ }`. E.g. in `addObserver` you would do: `observersLock.sync { observers.append(DispatchWorkItem { block() })) }`